# Yum says "wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package."

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I have Centos 6.7 and run this command

```
sudo yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
```

And I got this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, post-transaction-actions
Setting up Install Process
wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | 4.5 kB     00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-UthqQc/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm: wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-UthqQc/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

This package simply has an .repo file in /etc/yum.repo.d/. Why does yum refuse to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because apparently the package *wandisco-git-release* is already installed, but with a higher version than *6-1*.

There are two ways from here:

- find a more recent version of wandisco-git-release if you need to upgrade
- force a downgrade: `yum downgrade http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm`

Comment: I just ran "sudo yum info  http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm" => Error: No matching Packages to list. Turns out no such package is installed?

Comment: that is now how you check what package is installed locally. You should run `rpm -q wandisco-git-release`, or `rpm -qa | grep wandisco`...

Comment: I was able to find this package with rpm -qa | grep wandisco. Removed it with rpm -e <packagename>. Ran yum install again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This script helps me to install and upgrade to the latest version of Git and WANdisco yum repo installation. 
Repo URL: https://github.com/saifulislamrokon/deployment/blob/master/installgit

```
#!/bin/bash

centosversion=`rpm -qa \*-release | grep -Ei "oracle|redhat|centos" | cut -d"-" -f3`
echo "######################################################################################################"
echo "CentOS $centosversion server detected, Git 2* will install and configre as per centos $centosversion"
echo "######################################################################################################"

if [ $centosversion -eq "6" ]; then
echo 
echo "# Git YUM repo installing as per Centos 6"
echo
yum install -y http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
echo
echo "Congratulations Wandisco YUM repo installed Successfully on the system "
echo
echo "Now installing Git on $hostname server"
yum install git -y
yum update git -y
fi

if [ $centosversion -eq "7" ]; then
echo 
echo "# Git YUM repo installing as per Centos 7"
echo
yum install -y http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm
echo
echo "Now installing Git on $hostname server"
yum install git -y
yum update git -y

fi 

clear

echo "GIT Latest version installed Successfully"
git --version

echo "Thanks :: Saiful Islam Rokon Akon"

exit 0
```